# Extra NIC extranet IP issues

Tags: apache2, 16.04, ping, nic

For the question scroll down past italic font :)

**A quick recap:**
*Started with `FreeBSD` but it was a pain to install on `Hyper-V` environment, then tried with `CentOS`, easy install but I found documentation and guides not being 100% correct - follow a guide 100% but ex. Virtual Host would not work, but If I added steps from other documentation it would work, that was for almost every guide I tried.
So I thought o.k. put it on `HW` and not `hyper-V`, found an old Intel 2700MUD, but after install I had the audacity to move Ethernet cable to other `NIC`, on boot up Kernel crash or what its called - num lock and sroll lock blinking after it has loaded something.*

*So I "ended up" with Ubuntu, easy to install only issue is the GPU in Intel 2700MUD is not working out of the box on Ubuntu, but I live with SSH and maybe later I find fix for the GPU.*

YES you guessed it, newbie with nix but many years with MS so I prefer the GUI, but I must say I found it easy to adapt to Ubuntu via SSH, but I still need to check commands to use :).

**O.k. here is my little obstacle, the on-board NIC:**
"82574L Gigabit Network Connection" its getting a IP address from DHCP x.x.1.41(Routerboard 1100AHx2"), everything is working as it should.

**I have also added an extra NIC - with 2 ports, I would like to use as NIC for extranet for apache:**
"82546EB Gigabit Ethernet Controller (Copper)"
I can see on startup og restarts networking that the 2 ports is given an DHCP address x.x.0.34 and 35, but it will not answer to ping on the address', I can see via ifconfig RX packets and RX bytes raises slowly with ping, there is no raise in TX.

So I have tried with static address on the NIC same issue no connection, change to "auto", restart networking its stuck on restarting, if I clear it and run a status its:

```
Active: activating (start) since Fri 2016-05-13 23:00:19 CEST; 4min 38s ago
```

If i run start networking it starts immediately:

```
Active: active (exited) since Fri 2016-05-13 23:05:51 CEST; 1s ago
```

And I can see from DHCP lease its renewed on the NIC but no ping og routing to any of the 2 address' I can SSH to the address'

The idea is to route Internet traffic to x.x.0.34 address and keep 1.41 and the on-board NIC x.x.1.41 for administration, but at the moment its the other way around.

I just noticed:

```
manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man4/em.4freebsd.html 

Intel PRO/1000 MT Dual Port Server Adapter (82546) 
Intel PRO/1000 MT Quad Port Server Adapter (82546EB)
```

I have 2 ports "82546" but `lshw` gives:

```
product: 82546EB Gigabit Ethernet Controller (Copper)
```

Is that the issue and how can I change this?